# Backend of Prestashop Product Description Field hidden overflow

Tags: css, prestashop

I've got a Prestashop 1.7.1.1 wherein the backend when you edit the product description with images, it doesn't overflow properly.

I tried forcing the overflow in the CSS file `overflow:scroll!important` but that didn't do anything.

Has anyone encountered this bug and is aware of a fix/workaround?

Comment: Are you using Firefox? since that has for some time had an issue handling `overflow: !important`